# Cookie data cannot be unarchived in Swift 2 (AppleTV)

Tags: swift, swift2, tvos, apple-tv

When my app try to unarchive the cookie data with the following code, it always crashes.

```
if cookieData.length > 0 {
    let cookies: [NSHTTPCookie] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(cookieData) as! [NSHTTPCookie]
    for cookie: NSHTTPCookie in cookies {
            NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Could you tell me how I can fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. The following code does work:

```
if cookieData.length > 0 {
    if let cookies: [NSHTTPCookie] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(cookieData) as? [NSHTTPCookie]{
        for cookie: NSHTTPCookie in cookies {
            NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
}
```